# Buttons not displaying in linear layout

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

Hi all
my need is that buttons must show at bottom, so my code as

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="12dip">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_multiselectable"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
  </ListView>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"           

     android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip" android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    my buttons code here
</LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

But when items in list are less (until scroll bar of list view is not enable), Buttons are visible, but when items in list are more, buttons are not visible, although I scrolled list item to last row, but at last buttons are not displaying. How can I solve it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is giving `ListView` all the space it needs, because it considers its children sequentially and doesn't take into account those that follow.

My suggestion is to use RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
  <ListView ...
           android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
  <LinearLayout ...
           android:layout_below="@id/list"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     ...buttons...
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add more details to attributes of list view and linearlayout, please.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure. But you may try to set the weight of your listview.

```
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_multiselectable"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
  </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimumheight of listview
e.g.    320*480
listview height = 430
button's layout height = 50