# buttons are not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml code (i followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873523/buttons-not-displaying-in-linear-layout), but its not working):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webChapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/webChapter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back To Menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNavi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quiz" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the graphical one :

[image]

My buttons are not displayed when my webview become too tall. What should i do? Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webChapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back To Menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNavi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quiz" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks :D
But what is the different of using android:layout_below="webviewid" and android:layout_above="linearid"? why the first one is not working but the second is working?

Comment: @BlazeTama By setting android:layout_below="webviewid", you indicate your layout to be below your webview, but if your webview is too big, your layout will be out of the screen. By setting android:layout_above="linearid", you indicate your webview to be above your layout. I understand it is pretty hard to understand at the beginning (I remember :p) but the only suggestion I can do is keep practicing and it will make it clearer to you. The other way to do it is to replace your relativelayout with a vertical linear one, to make your webview 0dp height and 1weight, and linear with wrap_content.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes its a little hard, but your explanation make me understand better :D

Answer (score 1):

Try below Layout, Hope it works for you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webChapter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back To Menu" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNavi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Example" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Quiz" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above code will have buttons down the webview. If you can use the buttons above the webview, then there is no need of using weights also. you can put webview below the buttons layout.

Answer (score 1):

hi try this following one

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webChapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnLayout"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/webChapter">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back To Menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNavi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quiz" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may fix a height to your webview, or maybe define an id to your LinearLayout and set the property `android:layout_above` on your webView to guarantee that your webview will be above buttons not floating over them.

Try something like this:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webChapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lowerBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Comment: Thanks :D
But your answer make my app force close. Its because the android:layout_below="@+id/webChapter". 
Its a circular dependencies :D

Comment: Oops, just remove the below part